# Java android remove a rectangle and draw the rest of the image

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I am trying to crop a rectangle from a bitmap and draw the rest of the image on a canvas.Could achieve that so far.Could you please help? Code is as below-

```
1. //draw activity on the canvas. this returns a bitmap used in Bitmap.createBitmap(3)
 activity.getWindow().getDecorView().draw(canvas);

2. //get the coordinates that I want to clip.
 Rect removeImage = new rect(coordinates of rect portion)

3. //check that I can get the cropped image 
Bitmap croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, leftCrop, topCrop,    rightCrop, bottomCrop);

4. //Now I want to get the remaining canvas and remove the rectangular region 
?????????
```

Comment: its `createBitmap(Bitmap source, 
                int x, 
                int y, 
                int width, 
                int height)` and not `createBitmap(Bitmap source, 
                int x, 
                int y, 
                int right, 
                int bottom)`, also what do you mean by `"I want to get the remaining canvas"`?

Comment: What I meant was that createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height) gives me the cropped image (rectangle starting at x,y having width and height I specify) where as what I want is to keep the remaining image as show here http://www.screencast.com/t/iZlJ0cCDrIH

Comment: so use `Canvas` api to remove / clear any area from your original `Bitmap`

Comment: I have got the whole screen using canvas api and then have got the coordinates of the region that i want to remove from the canvas and want to get the image that I have given in the screen cast.

Comment: this is what I doing https://www.screencast.com/t/hO33wBHc to remove the rectangle from the image but couldn't get the desired results screencast.com/t/iZlJ0cCDrIH . whereas this is what I am getting https://www.screencast.com/t/uekl9MZVex8U. any suggestions??

Comment: figured it out this is what I did `Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN));
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(hole,p);
        canvas.save();
`

Comment: Please post a **complete** code example. This means you should have a class and method, just like you do in your real code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a rectangular portion from the bitmap of an activity we can use following code-

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), ARGB_8888);        
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN));
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawRect(rect,p);
    canvas.save();
```

You can manually calculate the rectangle coordinates or supply yours. I passed the view and used the following -

```
    Rect coordinates = new Rect();
    int[] xyLocation = new int[2];
    if (view == null) {
        return coordinates;
    }
    view.getLocationOnScreen(xyLocation);
    coordinates.left = xyLocation[0];
    coordinates.top = xyLocation[1];
    coordinates.right = coordinates.left + view.getWidth();
    coordinates.bottom = corrdinates.top + view.getHeight();
    return coordinates;
```

[image: removed rectangle from activity screen shot]